# Provisioning profile force update issues

Tags: ios, app-store, code-signing, provisioning-profile, updating

I had the live (app store) version of my app installed on my test device. This was the distribution one so it was using the iOS distribution provisioning profile and the correct code sign profile.

The trunk version of my app with the release configuration uses the same stuff; provisioning profile and code sign identity. I was able to install that over the app store build. But I wasn't able to do it with a version of the app I've branched out with. I am using the same provisioning profile and code signing identity.

In summary:

Updating app store build with trunk build worked fine, but updating app store build with branched version didn't work. The app installed about 3/4 of the way and then froze. I think it's a provisioning profile issue but I'm using the same info with trunk build and it works? Any ideas??

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't set all the code signing configurations to match. Debug and release were matching but not QA. Once i matched them to trunk it worked like a charm.